# Poisson equation spherical-radial only coordinates with second type boundary condition at the origin

Tags: boundary-value-problem, spherical-coordinates, poissons-equation

I have an issue with a basic Poisson's equation:

$$ \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r r^2 \partial_r V = - f(r)$$

with $r > 0$, $f(r) > 0$ has the following property:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} r^2 f(r) d r = 1 $$

and the boundary condition is of second type:

$$ \partial_r V \vert_{r=0} = 0 $$

Do you have an idea ? I checked a big textbook on PDEs I did not find it.

**What I tried**

I performed a direct integration, this leads to divergence in $r = 0$ and the same for the Green function integration $\propto 1/r$. My other idea was to sum on spherical Bessel functions ($j_0$ only), using eigenvalue decomposition but it is a long process so I want to make sure that there is no simple trick to do here... Thank you for reading.

**Edit**

I tried a decomposition with $j_0$ spherical Bessel function, it is not possible because they are not square integrable on $r \geq 0$ domain.

Comment: Do you know the asymptotic form of $f(r)$ for $0<r\ll 1$?

Comment: Hi Gonçalo, it dépends but it is well defined. It can be $f(0)=0$ or $\partial_r f(r=0) = 0$. We can adapt a bit $f$ if necessary (like self consistent field in Hartree theory).